# Adding a next button to my slideshow

Tags: javascript, slideshow

I would like to add a next button to this script instead of having it change images on a timed interval.  How would I go about doing this?

Here is the code:

```
<script src="viewimages.php"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

var curimg=0
function rotateimages(){
    document.getElementById("slideshow").setAttribute("src", ""+galleryarray[curimg])
    curimg=(curimg<galleryarray.length-1)? curimg+1 : 0
}

window.onload=function(){
    setInterval("rotateimages()", 4500)
}
</script>

<div style="width: 500px; height: 500px">
<img style="width: 100%; height: 100%;" id="slideshow" src="boston1.JPG" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a button and the onclick event.
Use your own rotateimage function and add it with onclick to your html button. The button could be something like that:

```
<button onclick="rotateimages()">Next</button>
```

Your hole code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var curimg=0
function rotateimages(){
    document.getElementById("slideshow").setAttribute("src", ""+galleryarray[curimg])
    curimg=(curimg<galleryarray.length-1)? curimg+1 : 0
}
</script> 

<!-- Your new button -->
<button onclick="rotateimages()">Next</button>


<div style="width: 500px; height: 500px">
<img style="width: 100%; height: 100%;" id="slideshow" src="boston1.JPG" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove this:

```
window.onload=function(){
    setInterval("rotateimages()", 4500)
}
```

And add a button to your HTML:

```
<button onclick="rotateimages()">Next</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Make a button like this;

```
 <button onclick="rotateimages()">Next</button>
```

And remove

```
window.onload=function(){
    setInterval("rotateimages()", 4500)
}
```

from your javascript

The entire code will look like;

```
<script src="viewimages.php"></script>    
<script type="text/javascript">

var curimg=0
function rotateimages(){
    document.getElementById("slideshow").setAttribute("src", ""+galleryarray[curimg])
    curimg=(curimg<galleryarray.length-1)? curimg+1 : 0
}

</script>

<div style="width: 500px; height: 500px">
    <img style="width: 100%; height: 100%;" id="slideshow" src="boston1.JPG" />
</div>
<button onclick="rotateimages()">Next</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to stop and restart the interval. Easier to create a method to do it. And just call the rotateimages like the times does. If you do not want the interval, just get rid of the restartInterval method.

```
var curimg=0
function rotateimages(){
    document.getElementById("slideshow").setAttribute("src", ""+galleryarray[curimg])
    curimg=(curimg<galleryarray.length-1)? curimg+1 : 0
}

var _timer;
function restartInterval() {
    if(_timer) window.clearInterval(_timer);
    _timer = setInterval(rotateimages, 4500)
}

function next() {
    restartInterval();
    rotateimages();
}


window.onload=function(){
    restartInterval();
}
```